# Node.js Async | insert into postgresql database results from api

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, insert

I am quite newbie with node.js. What i am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Connect to my postgresql database and get info of a place (id, coordinates).
2. call a weather api and get the info of that spot using the coordinates obtained in the previous step.
3. Insert the returned json in the database. I get 8 hourly objects, with the weather info every 3 hours (0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21). I need to iterate through this objects and the store them in 8 records in the database.

I wrote the following code:

```
app.get('/getapi', function(req, res){
var json_bbdd;  
 //------------ BBDD CONNECTION----------------
            var pg = require('pg'); 
            var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres2@localhost/places";

            var client = new pg.Client(conString);
            client.connect(function(err) {
              if(err) {
                 console.log('could not connect to postgres');
              }
              client.query('SELECT * from places where id=3276', function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                 console.log('error running query'); 
                }
                json_bbdd=result.rows[0];

                var coords = JSON.parse(json_bbdd.json).coordinates;
                var id = json_bbdd.id;
                var input = {
                    query: coords[1] + ',' + coords[0] ,
                    format: 'JSON',
                    fx: '',
                    callback: 'MarineWeatherCallback'
                };


                var url = _PremiumApiBaseURL + "marine.ashx?q=" + input.query + "&format=" + input.format + "&fx=" + input.fx + "&key=" + _PremiumApiKey + "&tide=yes";

                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (json) {

                    var date= json.data.weather[0].date;

                          for (var i=0; i < 8; i++){

                          var hourly = json.data.weather[0].hourly[i];
                          var time= hourly.time;

                            client.query('INSERT into parte (id, date, time) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', [id, date, time], 
                            function(err, result) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('row inserted: ' + id + ' ' + time);
                                }

                            }); 

                          } // FOR

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e.message);
                    }
                });

                client.end();
              });
            });
});
```

The steps 1 and 2 are performed perfectly. The third step, on the other hand, does nothing and it doesn't even throw an error.

I read in this post: [node-postgres will not insert data, but doesn't throw errors either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502121/node-postgres-will-not-insert-data-but-doesnt-throw-errors-either) that using async module could help but i have no idea how to rewrite the code. I need some help.

Regards,
Aitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test your snippet, I can only help you with things which looks bad to my eyes.

1. It is better not to use jQuery on node server. There is excellent library called [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to do remote http requests.
2. You should better handle database errors because in your example your code will continue after DB error.
3. You are calling `client.end()` too early and at the time when you try to insert data to the database a connection is already closed. You have to move `client.end()` at the end of success and error functions and wait to all callbacks are done.
4. I think it is also better to use connection pool instead of `Client`.
5. You can possibly use JSON type in `PostgreSQL` to avoid serializing/deserializing JSON data in your code.

Here is revised example(untested). I didn't replace jQuery here, some minor tweaking included.

```
var pg = require('pg'); 
var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres2@localhost/places";

app.get('/getapi', function(req, res, next){
var json_bbdd;  
//------------ BBDD CONNECTION----------------

  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      // example how can you handle errors
      console.error('could not connect to postgres');
      return next(new Error('Database error'));
    }
    client.query('SELECT * from places where id=3276', function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.error('error running query');
        done();
        return next(new Error('Database error'));
      }

      json_bbdd = result.rows[0];

      var coords = JSON.parse(json_bbdd.json).coordinates;
      var id = json_bbdd.id;
      var input = {
        query: coords[1] + ',' + coords[0] ,
        format: 'JSON',
        fx: '',
        callback: 'MarineWeatherCallback'
      };


      var url = _PremiumApiBaseURL + "marine.ashx?q=" +
                input.query + "&format=" + input.format +
                "&fx=" + input.fx + "&key=" +
                _PremiumApiKey + "&tide=yes";

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {

          var date = json.data.weather[0].date;
          var callbacks = 0;

          for (var i=0; i < 8; i++) {

            var hourly = json.data.weather[0].hourly[i];
            var time= hourly.time;

            client.query(
              'INSERT into parte (id, date, time) VALUES($1, $2, $3)',
              [id, date, time], 
              function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log('row inserted: ' + id + ' ' + time);
                }
                callbacks++;
                if (callbacks === 8) {
                  console.log('All callbacks done!');
                  done();    // done(); is rough equivalent of client.end();
                }
            }); 

          } // FOR
        },
        error: function (e) {
           console.error(e.message);
           done();    // done(); is rough equivalent of client.end(); 
           return next(new Error('Http error'));
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your tips. Your code worked perfectly! I also changed the http call using the request module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now cam up with another problem...i was doubting of creating a new post but i think that maybe could have relation with the previous post.

The aim is to read from the database instead of one place 3 places and do the same process than before for each one.
The code is as follows (with the changes proposed by ivoszz):

```
app.get('/getapi', function(req, res, next){  
//------------ BBDD CONNECTION----------------

  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      // example how can you handle errors
      console.error('could not connect to postgres',err);
      return next(new Error('Database error'));
    }
    client.query('SELECT * from places where id>3274 and id<3278', function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.error('error running query',err);
        done();
        return next(new Error('Database error'));
      }

      var first_callback = 0;
      for (var y=0;  y<result.rows.length; y++) {
          var coords = JSON.parse(result.rows[y].json).coordinates;
          var id = result.rows[y].id;
          var input = {
            query: coords[1] + ',' + coords[0] ,
            format: 'JSON',
            fx: ''
          };

          var url = _PremiumApiBaseURL + "marine.ashx?q=" + input.query + "&format=" + input.format + "&fx=" + input.fx + "&key=" + _PremiumApiKey;

          request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {

              var date = body.data.weather[0].date;
              var callbacks = 0;

              for (var i=0; i < 8; i++) {


                var hourly = body.data.weather[0].hourly[i];

                client.query(
                  'INSERT into parte (id, date, time) VALUES($1, $2, $3)',
                  [id, date, hourly.time], 
                  function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log('row inserted: ' + id + ' iteration ' + i);
                    }
                    callbacks++;
                    if (callbacks === 8) {
                      console.log('All callbacks done!from id '+id);
                      //done();    // done(); is rough equivalent of client.end();
                      //res.send("done");
                    }
                }); 

              } // FOR
            }
            else { // if the API http request throws an error
               console.error(err);
               done();    // done(); is rough equivalent of client.end(); 
               return next(new Error('Http API error'));
            } 
          }); // REQUEST API URL

      first_callback++;
      if (first_callback === result.rows.length-1) {
        console.log('All global callbacks done!');
        done();    // done(); is rough equivalent of client.end();
        res.send("done");
      }} 
    }); // SELECT from pg
  }); // CONNECT to pg
}); // app.get
```

I don't know why it tries to insert the id=3277 three times instead of inserting id=3275, id=3276 and then id=3277... what it does instead is: it inserts the first 8 records ok the first time (id=3277), but then it throws an error saying that the records are already inserted (primary key=id,date,time) with id 3277...

It seems that first does the 3 iterations of the first FOR and then does the 3 iteration of the second FOR but with the info of the last iteration(place). I can't understand it very well...